# iPhone device Generation

Tags: iphone

I have the following code

```
@implementation UIDevice(machine)

- (NSString *)machine
{
  size_t size;

  // Set 'oldp' parameter to NULL to get the size of the data
  // returned so we can allocate appropriate amount of space
  sysctlbyname("hw.machine", NULL, &size, NULL, 0); 

  // Allocate the space to store name
  char *name = malloc(size);

  // Get the platform name
  sysctlbyname("hw.machine", name, &size, NULL, 0);

  // Place name into a string
  NSString *machine = [NSString stringWithCString:name];

  // Done with this
  free(name);

  return machine;
}

@end

/* ... */

NSLog(@"device: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] machine]);
```

I am getting the output as:

```
Platforms:
-----------
iPhone1,1 
iPhone1,2 
iPod1,1   
iPod2,1
```

what does the two numbers appended after the iphone/ipod touch signify i,e (1,1 ) , (1,2) etc ?

Thanks
Biranchi

Comment: `NSString+stringWithCString` is deprecated, you should use `NSString+stringWithCString:encoding` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**iPhone1,1**: iPhone (original)
**iPhone1,2**: iPhone 3G
**iPhone2,1**: iPhone 3GS
**iPhone3,1**: iPhone 4
**iPhone4,1**: iPhone 4S

**iPod1,1**: iPod touch (original)
**iPod2,1**: iPod touch (2nd generation)
**iPod3,1**: iPod touch (3rd generation)
**iPod4,1**: iPod touch (4th generation)

**iPad1,1**: iPad (original)
**iPad2,1**: iPad 2
**iPad3,1**: iPad (3rd generation)

Answer (score -2):

Hardware revisions.  Think of them as a version of the platform.  You can also get this information from [`UIDevice`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html); why are you going so low-level?

Try this:

```
UIDevice *dev = [UIDevice currentDevice];
NSLog(@"Information for device '%@' (UDID '%@')", [dev name], [dev uniqueIdentifier]);
NSLog(@"Model: %@", [dev model]);
NSLog(@"OS: %@ version %@", [dev systemName], [dev systemVersion]);
```

...etc.